# Jquery autocomplete with Ajax from PHP not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The following ajax call

```
var whatever = [];
$.ajax({
    url: "myScript.php",
    success: function (response) {
        whatever = response.split(",");
    }
});
```

is generating:

```
"ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,"
```

Which are the values I want to use in JQuery autocomplete:

```
$('#conta').autocomplete({
        source:whatever
    });
```

However, nothing is displayed in the autocomplete popup.

If I type the values directly in JS, it works perfectly:

```
var whatever=[
        "ABC",
        "DEF","GHI","JKL"
    ];
```

But why isn't it working when generated by PHP?

Comment: `"ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,"` is string `whatever=[
        "ABC",
        "DEF","GHI","JKL"
    ];` is array. By the way whats your actual `response` result?

Comment: Sorry my bad reading ;) have you tried your ajax with `async: true` ?

Comment: No, I'm trying just that now

Comment: @AliMasudianPour I tried it, together with dataType:"json" but no luck

Comment: Data type was my misunderstood, I thought that you receive json response.

Answer (score 0):

In your source your php array needs to have rows with a "label" key like this:

```
foreach($rows as $key)
{
    $results[] = array('label' => ($key['nome']));
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

Also if your database rows are not encoded in utf8 you need to encode them otherwise it will be "null":

```
    $results[] = array('label' => utf8_encode($key['nome']));
```

UPDATE:

myScript.php:

```
...
foreach($rows as $key)
{
    $results[] = array('label' => ($key['nome']));
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $('#conta').autocomplete({
        source:"myScript.php"
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm using PDO to grab the data from the database

Comment: I guess your proposal doesn't work with PDO since I get the error:Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given

Comment: Something like the above perhaps. A PDO expert might give a better answer.

Comment: This is what I have originaly: foreach ($rows as $key) {
  echo($key['nome'].',');
 }

Comment: did you replace the source on the autocomplete? source:whatever should be source:"myScript.php"

Answer (score 0):

try put `$('#conta').autocomplete({
        source:whatever
    });`

in the success callback function

Comment: then whatever is empty

Comment: so your response is empty